# Increase number of entries in Chrome Auto-Complete

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, auto-form-fill

Following best security practices, I have unique passwords for multiple accounts at the same service. The passwords are long and random, generated by the Google Chrome password manager, and stored in my Google account.

When I get timed out and have to sign back in, the first 5 accounts go no problem. On the 6th and more, I need to open the password manager, as the passwords are not listed in the initial auto-complete box.

**How can I increase the list size of passwords to auto-complete in Google Chrome?**